# Why isn't my Jquery working after the third line

Tags: jquery

As soon as I started with the scroll() function it completely stopped working. I am trying to make $element fade-in when it is in view. I am pretty new to coding and I have spent hours trying to figure this out on my own.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa.fa-caret-square-o-down').addClass('load');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        function get_window_position() {
            var $window = $(window);
            var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
            var window_height = $window.height();
            var window_bottom = (window_top_position + window_height);
            var $element = $('.element');
            var element_top = $element.offset().top;
            var element_height = $element.height();
            var element_bottom = (element_top + element_height);
            $element.each(get_window_position) {

                if ((window_bottom > element_top) && (window_top_position < element_bottom)) {
                    $('.element').addClass('load');
                } else {
                    $('.element') removeClass('load');
                };
            };
        };

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Should the title read "Why IS my jQuery not working ..."?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function like this:

```
function doStuff() {
  ...
}
```

The code within won't actually run until you call the function with `doStuff()`. Also, jQuery's `each` function takes a callback function as a parameter. You pass a callback function then also seem to be defining another function with incorrect syntax. You can do something like
`$element.each(function(){...});` or `$element.each(myCallbackFunction);`

more information here: https://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: I call it after I declare the variables: "$element.each(get_window_position)"

Comment: Yes but when you define a function as follows: `function foo() {...}`. The code within is not actually run until you call `foo()` outside of the function. You have that call within the function definition so it won't actually run until you call it from somewhere else.

Comment: no matter what I do the console says that I am missing a semi-colon  @  $element.each(get_window_position) {

Comment: jQuery's `each` function takes a callback function as a parameter. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do because you pass a callback function then also seem to be trying to define another function after that. You could have `$element.each(function() { ... });` or just `$element.each(get_window_position);`. In the first example you define the behavior within the anonymous function and in the second the code within the get_window_position  function would run.  
More information at https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.
(First of all, you have not shown your complete / relevant HTML so its not clear if you have only one `.element` or multiple. I'm assuming you have multiple.)

1. Once you have defined anonymous function, (usually) you don't need to define another function inside it.
2. The way you are using `.each` is weird (and of course incorrect) that's why you are getting error `missing semicolon`.
3. As you are using `$element` to get `top`, `height` etc outside `.each` you are going to get the values for first `.element` only. Which isn't probably what you want.

Here is the updated code that should help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa.fa-caret-square-o-down').addClass('load');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        
        var $window = $(window);
        var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
        var window_height = $window.height();
        var window_bottom = (window_top_position + window_height);
        
        $('.element').each(function() {
          var $element = $(this);
          var element_top = $element.offset().top;
          var element_height = $element.height();
          var element_bottom = (element_top + element_height);

          if ((window_bottom > element_top) && (window_top_position < element_bottom)) {
            $element.addClass('load');
          } else {
            $element.removeClass('load');
          };
        });

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```